# Почему при переносе сайта с хостинга на хостинг ошибки в кодировке?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, кодировка, хостинг

при переносе сайта на wordpress с лучшего хостинга с характеристиками:

> php 7.0 Версия клиента бд: libmysql - 5.1.73 phpMyAdmin 4.0.10.14

на другой, более устаревший, с характеристиками:

> php 5.4.6 Версия MySQL-клиента: 5.0.22 Используется расширение PHP:
>   mysqli MySQL-кодировка: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8) phpMyAdmin - 2.11.11.3

По бд экспортировал, как обычный импорт с заменой для совместимости
**utf8mb4** на **utf8** и **utf8mb4_unicode_ci** на **utf8_unicode_ci** в *notepad++*, так и дела экспорт с максимальной совместимостью с версией mysql40 - всегда ошибки с кодировкой, т.к.
при заходе в таблицу бд wp_options уже вижу надписи строк такого рода

```
blogname ??????? «?????? ??????»
blogdescription ????????????? ????? ? 20 ?? ?? ??????
```

а на самом сайте - отображается (модифицированная) тема почему-то со стандартными настройками и надписями на латинице и кирилицей в виде (???). В админку попасть не могу - при заходе на страницу получаю ошибку:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at D:...\httpdocs\wp-includes\functions.php:3740) in
>   D:...\httpdocs\wp-includes\pluggable.php on line 1224

А, если включаю дебаг, то и дополнительные:

> Notice: load_plugin_textdomain was called with an argument that is
>   deprecated since version 2.7 with no alternative available. in
>   D:...\httpdocs\wp-includes\functions.php on line 3740
>
> Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in
>   D:...\httpdocs\wp-content\plugins\shortpixel-image-optimiser\wp-shortpixel.php
>   on line 3177
>
> Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in
>   D:...\httpdocs\wp-content\plugins\shortpixel-image-optimiser\wp-shortpixel.php
>   on line 3179
>
> Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in
>   D:...\httpdocs\wp-content\plugins\shortpixel-image-optimiser\wp-shortpixel.php
>   on line 3181
>
> Notice: Р’С‹Р·РІР°РЅРЅС‹Р№ РјРµС‚РѕРґ РєРѕРЅСЃС‚СЂСѓРєС‚РѕСЂР°
>   РєР»Р°СЃСЃР° WP_Widget СЃС‡РёС‚Р°РµС‚СЃСЏ СѓСЃС‚Р°СЂРµРІС€РёРј СЃ
>   РІРµСЂСЃРёРё 4.3.0! РСЃРїРѕР»СЊР·СѓР№С‚Рµ
>   __construct() . in D:...\httpdocs\wp-includes\functions.php on line 3625

а на главной в таком случае - белую страницу с ошибкой:

> Sorry, but recursing filters on "the_content" breaks NextGEN Gallery.
>   Please see https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17817 and
>   NGG_DISABLE_FILTER_THE_CONTENT

Comment: потому что кодировки в старых версиях mysql utf8mb4_unicode_ci  и конвертировать почти не реально, это же вордпресс...

Comment: @Naumov не очень понял ваш комментарий, т.к. это ведь про mysql идет речь, там при заливке кодируются коряво - при чем тут вордпресс? он лишь данные подтягивает с базы такие, какие ему предоставлены. и у людей в целом получается таким образом перекодировать  базу - почему вдруг не реально? уверен, что существует правильный способ!

Comment: вы делаете дамп а файл в кодировки utf8mb4 но сравнение базы utf8. А при конвертации из одной кодировки вы в большинстве случаев получите ????

Comment: @Naumov вы не совсем понимаете, что я делаю. 
как оказалось, ответ прост до примитива - нужно было всего лишь заменить в файле config.php строчку:
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');
на
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
и все работает!

Comment: Опубликуйте как ответ этот коментарий может кумото полезно будет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нужно было всего лишь заменить в файле config.php строчку: `define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');` на `define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');` и все работает!